# how to slove 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Flutter not found that type of error in Xcode for build application,I have try to schema in flutter but it could not build the app and Xcode could not build the IOS Application , so how can i Solve this i have already use flutter clean and flutter pub get to solve this but it could not build the app

Answer (score 0):

Delete pods folder, .symlinks folder, Podfile.lock then navigate to ios folder. Run pod install. Then build from xcode. Make sure you have enough space on your machine to build it too